# Shark for profiling iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, shark

I am using Shark to profile my application on iphone.
As per instruction in Shark user guide from 
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SharkUserGuide/SelectingExecutiontoSampleorTrace/SelectingExecutiontoSampleorTrace.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005233-CH13-SW19

I am able to generate profile for my application. But most of functions in my application appear as unknown under symbol header. This is because I am using release version of application. The user guide suggest that symbol information can be generated by using symbolification information and symbol rich binary of application. So first I generated debug version of application retaining the debug information then generated release version and used shark to profile and then used FILE/symbolicate option and selected the debug version of application from Debug-iphoneOs. I get error symbolification failed.
Can anyone suggest a method to eliminate this error?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to profile your iPhone app with symbols using File->Symbolicate, I believe you need to profile the debug version on your iPhone, not the release version.  At least that's how I've gotten it to work in the past.  That way when you symbolicate using the build in Debug-iphoneos, you're referencing the same image.