# Performance metrics for iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, performance

Is there a good way to record performance metrics (like number of times a function is called) for an iPhone app? I can't find any decent performance tools for it.

Comment: This question is very similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379348/how-to-find-performance-bottlenecks-in-an-iphone-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Shark](http://developer.apple.com/tools/sharkoptimize.html) like you can for normal OS X apps.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834135/shark-for-profiling-iphone-app) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326078/how-exactly-can-i-use-shark-to-profile-my-iphone-app) for more info.

Comment: Does Shark still exist? If not, maybe you should updated your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are aware of [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), are you?